# Gemalto card reader Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, card-reader

We have just received Gemlato USB Token for grade signing. Our service is available only inside the University. However, I am having trouble making it work properly in ubuntu 14.04. Drivers are installed (pcsc_scan results are available) and I tried to follow those instructions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommonAccessCard

However, every time I visit the page that is supposed to use Token, I receive this message "HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden: SSL client certificate is required.
Internet Information Services (IIS)"

I don't understand how to do this "This card reader uses the ccid driver. Since it uses a serial port connection, you must tell pcscd where it is located." (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommonAccessCard#Gemplus_GemPC_Card_.28PCMCIA.29)

```
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.4.22 (c) 2001-2011, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Compiled with PC/SC lite version: 1.8.10
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: Gemalto USB Shell Token V2 (B0EE12B1) 00 00

Mon Dec  1 08:39:03 2014
Reader 0: Gemalto USB Shell Token V2 (B0EE12B1) 00 00
  Card state: Card inserted, 
  ATR: 3B 16 96 41 73 74 72 69 64

ATR: 3B 16 96 41 73 74 72 69 64
+ TS = 3B --> Direct Convention
+ T0 = 16, Y(1): 0001, K: 6 (historical bytes)
  TA(1) = 96 --> Fi=512, Di=32, 16 cycles/ETU
    250000 bits/s at 4 MHz, fMax for Fi = 5 MHz => 312500 bits/s
+ Historical bytes: 41 73 74 72 69 64
  Category indicator byte: 41 (proprietary format)

Possibly identified card (using /usr/share/pcsc/smartcard_list.txt):
3B 16 96 41 73 74 72 69 64
    Gemalto .NET v2.0
```